# Typescript 'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, type-declaration

In my nextjs project I have this code:

```js
const go = new global.Go()
```

`global.Go` is defined through [wasm](https://webassembly.org/).

When I run the `tsc` command I get the following error:

```
error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.
```

So I've created the file `types/global.d.ts` and I have add these lines:

```
export declare global {
  function Go(): unknown
}
```

but now I get this error:

```
error TS7009: 'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What `Class` is?

Comment: mmm, is an alias for `any`. I edit the question.

Comment: Are you just trying to define the construct signature? You can do that with the following syntax: `export declare global { Go: { new (): unknown } }`.

Comment: @CRice I get syntax error with `Go: { new (): unknown }`

Answer (score 1):

Like the error message says; give it a construct signature

```
export declare global {
  const Go: new () => Go
}
```

Comment: With this declaration I get the error: `Property 'Go' does not exist on type 'typeof globalThis'.`